# Header doesn't appear on the first page

Tags: header-footer

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\rhead{4th conferencet}

\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
 

 
\begin{document}

\title{Internet of Things (IoT) based Health Monitor Device\\
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
 \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}



\makeatother


\maketitle
```

Comment: Why do you have those `>` signs at the start of each line? Besides, what is your question?

Comment: '>' was added by mistake sorry. My question is the header doesn't appear on the first page . They appear on the rest of the pages. How to I put headers on the first page? Thanks

Comment: Put
`\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\maketitle`

Comment: IEEE does not appreciate changing their format/look.  Read the manual (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf).

Comment: The important question is why the hell you want a header in the first page? You really need put some information about the page on top of the title? What is not evident about the first page in 0 seconds, facing a huge title? On the oher hand, this class is a personal election or it is requerid to submitt somewhere?  In the second case, you should not change the default format.